# What was outside the singularity during the Big Bang?

Tags: big-bang, singularities

What was outside the proposed singularity during big bang?What was the size of singularity?

Comment: There is no proposed singularity and there is, based on current observational data and the best theory we have, no "outside". The only question we have is how we have to modify general relativity to have a better understanding of what really might have happened at T_cosmological = 0.

Comment: See [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/). There was no *outside* at the Big Bang.

Answer (score 0):

Einstein's General Relativity allows a wide range of models of singularities.  Singularities occur when space-time seems to have an edge or a hole: That is, when space-time ceases to be predictable by General Relativity.

One model of singularity allowed by General Relativity is the "Big Bang" singularity that occurs at time zero of an expanding universe such as ours.  At the Big Bang, General Relativity ceases to be able to describe conditions.  There is no "outside" at the Big Bang because inside/outside are space-time concepts that cease to have meaning if space-time can not be described.  Likewise, size is a space-time concept that is not meaningful at a singularity.

This link provides a helpful way to conceptualize the meaning of a space-time singularity:  http://www.einstein-online.info/spotlights/singularities.